# How would I incorporate datetime.timedelta to create csv of recurring dates for budget within a given period

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to generate a CSV cashflow of income and expenses during a set period (example 1 year). So far I've created cashflow.py and balance.py.

**cashflow.py**

```
    import datetime
    import pandas as pd
    import csv
    import os
    
    
    class CashFlow(object):
    
        def __init__(self, name='cashflow'):
            self.name = name
            self.columns = ['date_of_activity', 'description', 'amount']
            self.series = pd.DataFrame(columns=self.columns)
    
        def generate_series(self, description, amount, frequency='MS',
                            start=datetime.date(datetime.date.today().year, 1, 1),
                            end=datetime.date(datetime.date.today().year, 12, 31)):
            """Generate a new data series and append it to the existing data"""
            data = [(date_of_activity, description, amount)
                    for date_of_activity in pd.date_range(start, end, freq=frequency)]
            self.series = pd.concat(
                [self.series, pd.DataFrame(data, columns=self.columns)])
    
        def add_event(self, description, amount, date_of_activity):
            """Add a single event"""
            self.generate_series(description, amount, frequency='D',
                                 start=date_of_activity, end=date_of_activity),
    
        def export_to_csv(self, dirpath, filename):
            """ Export the data to a csv file."""
            """ Sort data by 1) date_of_activity ascending and 2) amount ascending before the export."""
    
            path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            with open(path, 'w') as csvfile:
                csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
                csv_writer.writerow(self.columns)
                self.series.sort_values(by=['date_of_activity', 'amount'], ascending=[
                                        True, True], inplace=True)
                for index, record in self.series.iterrows():
                    csv_writer.writerow(record)
```

**balance.py**

```
    import pandas as pd
    import plotly.express as px
    import datetime
    import cashflow
      
    cf = cashflow.CashFlow('Cash flow forecast')
    
    # Balance
    balance = 98000
    
    # start_date
    start_year = 2022
    start_month= 6
    start_day = 2
    
    # End date
    end_year = 2022
    end_month = 12
    end_day = 29 
     
    # Generate data
    cf.add_event('Original balance', balance, datetime.date(start_year, start_month, start_day))
    
    # weekly
    cf.generate_series('Food', -100, frequency='W',
                       start=datetime.date(2022, 6, 3), end=datetime.date(end_year, end_month, end_day))
    
    # Monthly
    cf.generate_series('Rent', -1500, frequency='M',
                       start=datetime.date(2022, 6, 3), end=datetime.date(end_year, end_month, end_day))
    
    # Quarterly
    cf.generate_series('subscription', -1500, frequency='Q',
                       start=datetime.date(2022, 6, 15), end=datetime.date(end_year, end_month, end_day))
    
    # One-offs
    cf.add_event('One off payment - auto', -5000, datetime.date(2023, 5, 15))
    
    #
    # Show the data
    print(cf.series)
    cf.export_to_csv('', 'balance.csv')
```

However the output still does not match up with the startdates that I have in balance.py.

```
    date_of_activity,description,amount
    2022-06-02 00:00:00,Original balance,98000
    2022-06-05 00:00:00,Food,-100
    2022-06-12 00:00:00,Food,-100
    2022-06-19 00:00:00,Food,-100
    2022-06-26 00:00:00,Food,-100
    2022-07-01 00:00:00,Rent,-1500
    2022-07-01 00:00:00,subscription,-1500
```

For example would how could I incorporate `datetime.timedelta`.

At the moment `Food` should start on `3-6-2022`, but in the output starts on the `5-6-2022`. It seems that the date frequency for week is fixed to Sundays?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that the date frequency for week is fixed to Sundays?

This is default, you might provide 3-letter code of day of week you want, for example to get THUrsdays of 1900 you can do

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
d1 = datetime.date(1900,1,1)  # this was monday
d2 = datetime.date(1900,12,31)
print(pd.date_range(d1,d2,freq='W-THU'))
```

output

```
DatetimeIndex(['1900-01-04', '1900-01-11', '1900-01-18', '1900-01-25',
               '1900-02-01', '1900-02-08', '1900-02-15', '1900-02-22',
               '1900-03-01', '1900-03-08', '1900-03-15', '1900-03-22',
               '1900-03-29', '1900-04-05', '1900-04-12', '1900-04-19',
               '1900-04-26', '1900-05-03', '1900-05-10', '1900-05-17',
               '1900-05-24', '1900-05-31', '1900-06-07', '1900-06-14',
               '1900-06-21', '1900-06-28', '1900-07-05', '1900-07-12',
               '1900-07-19', '1900-07-26', '1900-08-02', '1900-08-09',
               '1900-08-16', '1900-08-23', '1900-08-30', '1900-09-06',
               '1900-09-13', '1900-09-20', '1900-09-27', '1900-10-04',
               '1900-10-11', '1900-10-18', '1900-10-25', '1900-11-01',
               '1900-11-08', '1900-11-15', '1900-11-22', '1900-11-29',
               '1900-12-06', '1900-12-13', '1900-12-20', '1900-12-27'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='W-THU')
```

Comment: Is there something similar for freq-M? as in `cf.generate_series('Rent', -1500, frequency='M',
                   start=datetime.date(2022, 6, 3), end=datetime.date(end_year, end_month, end_day))`

Comment: `M` is month end, `BM` is business month end, `MS` is month start, `BMS` is business month start, same for quarters but with `Q` in place of `M`, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases